# How to make each button respond to that row only

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a Repeater which creates a table for multiple row with the same field name:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptContent">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table border="0" style="width: 95%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="width: 25%;">Name</td>
                        <td style="width: 25%;">Last Four SSN #</td>
                        <td style="width: 25%;">PDF Generator</td>
                    </tr>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%# Eval("name").ToString() %></td>
                        <td><%# Eval("ssn3").ToString() %></td>
                        <td><asp:Button ID="btnGeneratePDF" runat="server" Text="Generate PDF For" onclick="btnGeneratePDF_Click" /></td>
                    </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
```

My code behind looks like this:

```
public void writeData()
    {
        Conn = new SqlConnection(cString);
        Conn.Open();

        nameE = txtName.Text;

        var pdfPath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/PDFTemplates/9.pdf"));

        // Get the form fields for this PDF and fill them in!
        var formFieldMap = PDFHelper.GetFormFieldNames(pdfPath);
        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_01_0_[0]"] = txtName.Text;

        sqlCode = "SELECT * FROM [db].[dbo].[TablePDFTest] WHERE [name] = '" + nameE + "'";

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sqlCode, Conn))
        {
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            using (reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_02_0_[0]"] = reader.GetValue(1).ToString();
                        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_04_0_[0]"] = reader.GetValue(2).ToString();
                        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_05_0_[0]"] = reader.GetValue(3).ToString();
                        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_07_0_[0]"] = reader.GetValue(4).ToString();
                        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].social[0].TextField1[0]"] = reader.GetValue(5).ToString();
                        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].social[0].TextField2[0]"] = reader.GetValue(6).ToString();
                        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].social[0].TextField2[1]"] = reader.GetValue(7).ToString();
                        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].social[0].TextField2[2]"] = reader.GetValue(8).ToString();
                        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].social[0].TextField2[3]"] = reader.GetValue(9).ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Requester's name and address (hard-coded)
        formFieldMap["topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].f1_06_0_[0]"] = "Medical Group\n2700 Wr Ave\nPurchase, NY 10232";

        var pdfContents = PDFHelper.GeneratePDF(pdfPath, formFieldMap);

        PDFHelper.ReturnPDF(pdfContents, "Compl.pdf");
    }
```

How can I make it so if there are more than one entries each button will query by `[name]` where the last four ssn is different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, just a nod to using parameters...

Anyway, a lot of ways to do this, but one could be to add a commandargument value to your button (and then evaluate it in your code behind).

```
<asp:Button 
   ID="btnGeneratePDF" 
   runat="server" 
   Text="Generate PDF For" 
   CommandArgument = '<%# Eval("L4_SSN") %>' 
   onclick="btnGeneratePDF_Click" />
```

Then you'd need to make sure you had a field in your SELECT statement such as `RIGHT(SSN,4) as L4_SSN`

And finally, you'd modify your `btnGeneratePDF_Click` sub to evaluate `e.CommandArgument`...

Comment: I am sending two parameters because the name can be same or the last four can be same. So I am queried against both the name and last four SSN so there is only one match but when I run it the query is blank for some reason.